# loading shared libraries

Tags: bash, shell, unix, libraries, shared

I am having problems with loading shared libraries when running a script that needs them:

`error while loading shared libraries: libirc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

However, I think my setup is OK:

```
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /lfs/data0/g_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and `ls /lfs/data0/g_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64` shows that `libirc.so` is really there.

`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns correctly:

```
/lfs/data0/g_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64
```

It still does not work so I am a bit desperate... :)

Could anyone help me with that please?

Some useful info:

```
echo ${SHELL}
/bin/bash
```

Also, the script that i run contains this at the beginning:

```
#!/bin/csh
#PBS -z
#PBS -S /bin/csh

set PATH = /usr/local/x86_64/gnu/openmpi-1.4.5/bin
export PATH
```

Thanks !

Comment: Try `LD_DEBUG=all ./program` and see what that outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're running this on a cluster, in which case the problem is unrelated to your shell(s). Try with:

```
#PBS -v LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lfs/data0/g_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64"
```

It may also be worth noting that

```
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /lfs/data0/g_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64
```

is csh syntax, while you say you're running bash. The bash equivalent is

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lfs/data0/g_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64
```

and it's spacing sensitive.

Comment: Yes, I am running it on a  cluster but the #PBS -v thing gives same result actually. I tried your bash equivalent, and again same thing. However, regarding the shell, even though echo${SHELL} gives bash, I use  #PBS -S /bin/csh in my script. Doesn't that change the shell?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks nneonneo, here is what it gives: (i just paste the beginning of the message as it is quite long, let me know if the full output is necessary):

```
LD_DEBUG=all ./mpp_starter
 26489: 
 26489: file=librt.so.1 [0];  needed by ./mpp_starter [0]
 26489: find library=librt.so.1 [0]; searching
 26489:  search path=/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64/tls/x86_64:/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64/tls:/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64/x86_64:/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64      (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
 26489:   trying file=/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64/tls/x86_64/librt.so.1
 26489:   trying file=/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64/tls/librt.so.1
 26489:   trying file=/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64/x86_64/librt.so.1
 26489:   trying file=/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64/librt.so.1
 26489:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
 26489:   trying file=/lib64/librt.so.1
 26489: 
 26489: file=librt.so.1 [0];  generating link map
 26489:   dynamic: 0x0000003a74a06dc8  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x0000000000207bb0
 26489:     entry: 0x0000003a74802140  phdr: 0x0000003a74800040  phnum:                  9
 26489: 
 26489: 
 26489: file=libnuma.so.1 [0];  needed by ./mpp_starter [0]
 26489: find library=libnuma.so.1 [0]; searching
 26489:  search path=/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64       (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
 26489:   trying file=/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64/libnuma.so.1
 26489:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
 26489:   trying file=/usr/lib64/libnuma.so.1
 26489: 
 26489: file=libnuma.so.1 [0];  generating link map
 26489:   dynamic: 0x0000003a77207450  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x0000000000207d60
 26489:     entry: 0x0000003a770026d0  phdr: 0x0000003a77000040  phnum:                  7
 26489: 
 26489: 
 26489: file=libdl.so.2 [0];  needed by ./mpp_starter [0]
 26489: find library=libdl.so.2 [0]; searching
 26489:  search path=/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64       (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
 26489:   trying file=/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64/libdl.so.2
 26489:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
 26489:   trying file=/lib64/libdl.so.2
 26489: 
 26489: file=libdl.so.2 [0];  generating link map
 26489:   dynamic: 0x0000003a73a02da0  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x0000000000203100
 26489:     entry: 0x0000003a73800de0  phdr: 0x0000003a73800040  phnum:                  9
 26489: 
 26489: 
 26489: file=libirc.so [0];  needed by ./mpp_starter [0]
 26489: find library=libirc.so [0]; searching
 26489:  search path=/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64       (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
 26489:   trying file=/lfs/data0/gstar_local/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64/libirc.so
 26489: 
 26489: file=libirc.so [0];  generating link map
 26489:   dynamic: 0x00007f6635da51b0  base: 0x00007f6635c66000   size: 0x0000000000142bc0
 26489:     entry: 0x00007f6635c6d040  phdr: 0x00007f6635c66040  phnum:                  5
 26489: 
 26489:
```

Comment: So far, that seems to indicate that the library was found successfully...maybe you should post the full output.

Comment: Ok, i post it below. Thanks!

Comment: It actually exceeds the number of characters limit. I put it there:    https://dl.dropbox.com/u/83005427/debugall_output.dat

Comment: Nowhere in that output does it say it failed to load `libirc`. Is the message being printed out by another machine (remote node), perhaps?

Comment: Hum, I ran the LD_DEBUG=all ./program command on the server, but the job is actually submitted to a queue (on a cluster) and the error message is generated there.